Is there a preferred way of handling mock types and automock?
These sort of build warnings...
multiple methods are never used

led me down a massive rabbit hole because the code was also tied to some real issue. But ultimately, it seems like the Rust compiler gets confused when it's this sort of setup...
cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(test)] {
        ....
        pub use crate::agent::some_service::some_service_proxy::MockSomeServiceProxy as SomeServiceProxy;
       ...
    } else {
       ...
        pub use crate::agent::some_service::some_service_proxy::SomeServiceProxy;
       ...
    }
}

and then...
#[cfg_attr(test, mockall::automock)]

Everything that gets sets up below this will have this sort of error - methods not being used, structs not being constructed etc. When I check the rust analyzer, it shows SomeServiceProxy as...
MockSomeServiceProxy

but I would have expected
SomeServiceProxy

Is there a better way of handling this? I probably need to handle the importing differently to use automock?
From looking at the package, it looks like my predecessor used...
#[allow(dead_code)]

to suppress these kind of warnings since it was used in places where the code was being used as well. I would prefer to not use this annotation though if possible.

When running cargo test, a separate build of your library is created with #[cfg(test)] enabled. It looks like you're changing the exported symbols when under test and sounds like that means various types are left un-exported (meaning the compiler could see them as unused). You should generally not change what is normally exported when under test.

rust-analyzer shows the test import because it enables cfg(test). You can configure this with rust-analyzer.cfg.setTest (but if you disable it test-related code won't have IDE functionality).

I don't want to disable. Ideally I would be able to address all these warnings because it makes it hard to figure out what is an actual issue when looking through what rust-analyzer is pointing out. I'm just learning Rust but how this was set up seems bad but not sure if this is an artifact we have to deal with because of automock
